# C++; how to compare the string values of different iterators traversing the same string vector

Tags: c++, iterator, strcmp

If two vector iterators `iit` and `min` traverse the same `vector<string>`, how can i compare the string values at the locations the pointers are at? i want to be able to do this:

```
(strcmp(*iit, *min) < 0)
```

Comment: How flexible do you need to be in respect of locale-specific string collation rules? Not that they make any difference for ASCII strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`std::basic_string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) member function:

```
iit->compare(*min) < 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could answer this by asking yourself the following simple questions:

1) How can I get access to an element of an `std::vector` from an iterator?

2) What kind of operations can I perform on a string?

Both of these are easily answerable by looking up some documentation. This would lead you to a solution, such as the following: Compare the targets of the iterators using one of `std::string`'s comparison operators:

```
*iit < *min
```

Answer (score 0):

If `iit` and `min` are iterators to a `std::vector<std::string>` then `*iit` and `*min` is a `std::sting`.  Since `std::string` has a [`operator <`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) you can comapre them as

```
if (*iit < *min)
    // do stuff
```